# Is there a name for words rhyming from two different stanzas?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, poetry, rhymes

Im analyzing this poem, and I noticed that none of the words rhyme with each other in a stanza, but words rhyme with another word from tge next stanza. I understand rhyme scheme is supposed to be within each stanza. Is there a word when rhyming occurs outside the stanzas???

“I heard the screams above the blood-fire street
Echo  sickly through disease  vestibules

The reaper gathers as he ridicules 
 The paddlers of flash, the buyers of meat.

Tonight the reaper walks with silent feet
 To visit we’re friends who sleep in gutters.

Near refuse cans. They awaken and utter
 Nothing, as if they knew their life’s complete...”

This is not the whole poem by Enrique B. Del Rosario.
I noticed that..
Street and meat and feet and complete
Vestibules and ridicules 
Gutters and utter
Rhyme, but each word that rhymes is from a different stanza.
Is there a term for something like this?

Comment: This is a sonnet. The rhymes are where they're supposed to be. The division into stanzas is unconventional. But lots of sonnets are divided into stanzas that rhymes cross. [See *The Windhover*.](https://www.bartleby.com/122/12.html)

Comment: You might want to look up the term rhyme schemes, typically given with capital letters for the same end rhymes. You can find them for styles of verse such as sonnets.

Comment: This question might also be better suited to https://writing.stackexchange.com/ or https://literature.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I know what rhyme schemes are, I just haven’t seen a term for when rhyming occurs outside a stanza. What type of rhyme scheme should I say this poem has? I can’t find the term for it.

Answer (score 2):

The term for linking different stanzas together by rhymes between them is called [chain rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rhyme).

A famous example is Robert Frost's *Stopping by Woods on a Snowy Evening*, which starts

> Whose woods these are I think I know.
>   His house is in the village though;
>   He will not see me stopping here
>   To watch his woods fill up with snow.
>
> My little horse must think it queer
>   To stop without a farmhouse near
>   Between the woods and frozen lake
>   The darkest evening of the year.

Here, the first two stanzas are linked by *here* rhyming with *queer, near, year*.

However, I don't know whether I'd call your poem *chain rhyme* or a sonnet with an unusual division into stanzas. Sonnets aren't usually classified as chain rhyme, no matter how they are divided into stanzas.